# Varnish Cache Miss - TTL decided by VCL is 0

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl, ttl

I'm unsure as to why the VCL is calculating the TTL to be 0 when I am setting the appropriate cache headers. I am hoping someone with a bit more experience may be able to spot something really obvious.

Here are the logs

```
varnish_1  | *   << BeReq    >> 18        
varnish_1  | -   Begin          bereq 17 pass
varnish_1  | -   Timestamp      Start: 1522327212.212730 0.000000 0.000000
varnish_1  | -   BereqMethod    GET
varnish_1  | -   BereqURL       /routes/%2F
varnish_1  | -   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
varnish_1  | -   BereqHeader    Host: localhost:8081
varnish_1  | -   BereqHeader    accept: application/ld+json
varnish_1  | -   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Mobile Safari/537.36
varnish_1  | -   BereqHeader    DNT: 1
varnish_1  | -   BereqHeader    Referer: http://localhost:8081/
varnish_1  | -   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
varnish_1  | -   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
varnish_1  | -   BereqHeader    Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.917775181.1515688563; Phpstorm-53bb5460=b5be55f5-d679-4bb9-b2b2-108bdac978eb; PHPSESSID=3gc3fulg7kdv0k5hiaitmlaq7e
varnish_1  | -   BereqHeader    If-None-Match: "90cd705e5c80bbb83aa64439f9b18c62"
varnish_1  | -   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 172.18.0.1
varnish_1  | -   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 18
varnish_1  | -   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
varnish_1  | -   VCL_return     fetch
varnish_1  | -   BackendOpen    23 boot.default 172.18.0.4 80 172.18.0.5 34084
varnish_1  | -   BackendStart   172.18.0.4 80
varnish_1  | -   Timestamp      Bereq: 1522327212.212948 0.000218 0.000218
varnish_1  | -   Timestamp      Beresp: 1522327217.902208 5.689478 5.689260
varnish_1  | -   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
varnish_1  | -   BerespStatus   200
varnish_1  | -   BerespReason   OK
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   Server: nginx/1.13.9
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   Content-Type: application/ld+json; charset=utf-8
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.3
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   Vary: Accept
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   Vary: Content-Type
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   Vary: Authorization
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: deny
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=0, public, s-maxage=3600
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2018 12:40:17 GMT
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   Link: <http://localhost:8081/docs.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation"
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   ETag: "fe8fa0778f4ee8045999017ccf82c34f"
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   Cache-Tags: /routes/%252F,/pages/3d07e6ba3a1d4ba1860a1846c0c1436b,/layouts/72ecbecdf0c140db8ac146dc69d70e33,/nav_bars/ef102fd0830442348273c924ff62249f,/component_groups/e0cbdc6f83f3444ba0392d20497c19e0,/component_groups/bd7c54c561a34442869369d9d655f08f,/
varnish_1  | -   TTL            RFC 3600 10 -1 1522327218 1522327218 1522327217 0 3600
varnish_1  | -   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   url: /routes/%2F
varnish_1  | -   TTL            VCL -1 3600 0 1522327218
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   X-Cacheable: NO:Not Cacheable
varnish_1  | -   BerespHeader   X-Cache-TTL: 0.000
varnish_1  | -   TTL            VCL 120 3600 0 1522327218
varnish_1  | -   VCL_return     deliver
varnish_1  | -   Storage        malloc Transient
varnish_1  | -   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
varnish_1  | -   ObjStatus      200
varnish_1  | -   ObjReason      OK
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      Server: nginx/1.13.9
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      Content-Type: application/ld+json; charset=utf-8
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.3
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      Vary: Accept, Content-Type, Authorization
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      X-Frame-Options: deny
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0, public, s-maxage=3600
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2018 12:40:17 GMT
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      Link: <http://localhost:8081/docs.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation"
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      ETag: "fe8fa0778f4ee8045999017ccf82c34f"
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      Cache-Tags: /routes/%252F,/pages/3d07e6ba3a1d4ba1860a1846c0c1436b,/layouts/72ecbecdf0c140db8ac146dc69d70e33,/nav_bars/ef102fd0830442348273c924ff62249f,/component_groups/e0cbdc6f83f3444ba0392d20497c19e0,/component_groups/bd7c54c561a34442869369d9d655f08f,/
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      url: /routes/%2F
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      X-Cacheable: NO:Not Cacheable
varnish_1  | -   ObjHeader      X-Cache-TTL: 0.000
varnish_1  | -   Fetch_Body     2 chunked stream
varnish_1  | -   BackendReuse   23 boot.default
varnish_1  | -   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1522327217.902374 5.689644 0.000166
varnish_1  | -   Length         3195
varnish_1  | -   BereqAcct      588 0 588 1972 3195 5167
varnish_1  | -   End            
varnish_1  | 
varnish_1  | *   << Request  >> 17        
varnish_1  | -   Begin          req 16 rxreq
varnish_1  | -   Timestamp      Start: 1522327212.212645 0.000000 0.000000
varnish_1  | -   Timestamp      Req: 1522327212.212645 0.000000 0.000000
varnish_1  | -   ReqStart       172.18.0.1 50692
varnish_1  | -   ReqMethod      GET
varnish_1  | -   ReqURL         /routes/%2F
varnish_1  | -   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
varnish_1  | -   ReqHeader      Host: localhost:8081
varnish_1  | -   ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
varnish_1  | -   ReqHeader      accept: application/ld+json
varnish_1  | -   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Mobile Safari/537.36
varnish_1  | -   ReqHeader      DNT: 1
varnish_1  | -   ReqHeader      Referer: http://localhost:8081/
varnish_1  | -   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
varnish_1  | -   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
varnish_1  | -   ReqHeader      Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.917775181.1515688563; Phpstorm-53bb5460=b5be55f5-d679-4bb9-b2b2-108bdac978eb; PHPSESSID=3gc3fulg7kdv0k5hiaitmlaq7e
varnish_1  | -   ReqHeader      If-None-Match: "90cd705e5c80bbb83aa64439f9b18c62"
varnish_1  | -   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 172.18.0.1
varnish_1  | -   VCL_call       RECV
varnish_1  | -   VCL_return     pass
varnish_1  | -   VCL_call       HASH
varnish_1  | -   VCL_return     lookup
varnish_1  | -   VCL_call       PASS
varnish_1  | -   VCL_return     fetch
varnish_1  | -   Link           bereq 18 pass
varnish_1  | -   Timestamp      Fetch: 1522327217.902388 5.689743 5.689743
varnish_1  | -   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
varnish_1  | -   RespStatus     200
varnish_1  | -   RespReason     OK
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.13.9
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Content-Type: application/ld+json; charset=utf-8
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.3
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Vary: Accept, Content-Type, Authorization
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: deny
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=0, public, s-maxage=3600
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2018 12:40:17 GMT
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Link: <http://localhost:8081/docs.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation"
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     ETag: "fe8fa0778f4ee8045999017ccf82c34f"
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Cache-Tags: /routes/%252F,/pages/3d07e6ba3a1d4ba1860a1846c0c1436b,/layouts/72ecbecdf0c140db8ac146dc69d70e33,/nav_bars/ef102fd0830442348273c924ff62249f,/component_groups/e0cbdc6f83f3444ba0392d20497c19e0,/component_groups/bd7c54c561a34442869369d9d655f08f,/
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     url: /routes/%2F
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     X-Cacheable: NO:Not Cacheable
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     X-Cache-TTL: 0.000
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 17
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Age: 0
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
varnish_1  | -   VCL_call       DELIVER
varnish_1  | -   RespUnset      url: /routes/%2F
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     X-Cache: MISS
varnish_1  | -   VCL_return     deliver
varnish_1  | -   Timestamp      Process: 1522327217.902479 5.689834 0.000091
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Content-Length: 3195
varnish_1  | -   Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
varnish_1  | -   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
varnish_1  | -   Timestamp      Resp: 1522327217.902553 5.689908 0.000074
varnish_1  | -   ReqAcct        568 0 568 2086 3195 5281
varnish_1  | -   End            
varnish_1  | 
varnish_1  | *   << Session  >> 16        
varnish_1  | -   Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
varnish_1  | -   SessOpen       172.18.0.1 50692 :80 172.18.0.5 80 1522327212.212513 21
varnish_1  | -   Link           req 17 rxreq
varnish_1  | -   SessClose      RX_TIMEOUT 10.695
varnish_1  | -   End
```

The TTL from RFC looks OK to me (I think). But then the TTL from the VCL is -1

Perhaps I've got a long header or something but if anyone can give a little advice I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks,

EDIT:
Here is my config (thought it may be helpful)

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;

backend default {
  .host = "api";
  .port = "80";
  # Health check
  #.probe = {
  #  .url = "/";
  #  .timeout = 5s;
  #  .interval = 10s;
  #  .window = 5;
  #  .threshold = 3;
  #}
}

# Hosts allowed to send BAN requests
acl ban {
  "localhost";
  "php";
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
  # Ban lurker friendly header
  set beresp.http.url = bereq.url;

  # Add a grace in case the backend is down
  set beresp.grace = 1h;

  if (bereq.http.Cookie ~ "(UserID|_session)") {
      set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Got Session";
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
  } elsif (beresp.ttl <= 0s) {
      # Varnish determined the object was not cacheable
      set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Not Cacheable";
      set beresp.http.X-Cache-TTL = beresp.ttl;
  } elsif (beresp.http.set-cookie) {
      # You don't wish to cache content for logged in users
      set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Set-Cookie";
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
  } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
      # You are respecting the Cache-Control=private header from the backend
      set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Cache-Control=private";
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
  } else {
      # Varnish determined the object was cacheable
      set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
  }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
  # Don't send cache tags related headers to the client
  unset resp.http.url;
  # Uncomment the following line to NOT send the "Cache-Tags" header to the client (prevent using CloudFlare cache tags)
  #unset resp.http.Cache-Tags;
  if (obj.hits > 0) {
       set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
  } else {
       set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
  }
}

sub vcl_recv {
  # Remove the "Forwarded" HTTP header if exists (security)
  unset req.http.forwarded;

  # To allow API Platform to ban by cache tags
  if (req.method == "BAN") {
    if (client.ip !~ ban) {
      return(synth(405, "Not allowed"));
    }

    if (req.http.ApiPlatform-Ban-Regex) {
      ban("obj.http.Cache-Tags ~ " + req.http.ApiPlatform-Ban-Regex);

      return(synth(200, "Ban added"));
    }

    return(synth(400, "ApiPlatform-Ban-Regex HTTP header must be set."));
  }
}

# From https://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Book/blob/master/vcl/grace.vcl
sub vcl_hit {
  if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
    # Normal hit
    return (deliver);
  } elsif (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
    # The backend is healthy
    # Fetch the object from the backend
    return (fetch);
  } else {
    # No fresh object and the backend is not healthy
    if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
      # Deliver graced object
      # Automatically triggers a background fetch
      return (deliver);
    } else {
      # No valid object to deliver
      # No healthy backend to handle request
      # Return error
      return (synth(503, "API is down"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, which Varnish version is it? Do you think you can try to reverse the order in ```Cache-Control``` to ```s-maxage=3600, max-age=0, public``` (although shouldn't make a difference, but who knows) :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DanielV. It wasn't the order thankfully - I'd hope if that were a bug it'd have been caught quite quickly as their docs show the priority it gives to the cache control headers. Luckily it was as simple as not having read the docs thoroughly enough (as it usually is) - it was the cookies in the end :). I can't mark it as correct for a couple of days though.

Answer (score 1):

After a chat on the IRC (user fgs was very helpful) I can read the logs a bit better and understand why this is happening.

vcl_recv is returning pass instead of lookup because cookies are sent in the request.

I missed the docs here:
https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/users-guide/increasing-your-hitrate.html#cookies